# How do I select element of spinner?

Tags: android

This my main result where we declare all `editText` and `spinner`:

```
public class Addresult extends AppCompatActivity {
    String subject[] = {"English", "Urdu", "Math", "Biology", "Chemistry", "Physics", "Computer"};
    Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5, sp6, sp7;
    EditText eng, urdu, math, bio, chem, phy, comp, r;
    Database database;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_addresult);
         database = new Database(this);
         sp1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         sp2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
         sp3 = findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
         sp4 = findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
         sp5 = findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
         sp6 = findViewById(R.id.spinner6);
         sp7 = findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
         eng = findViewById(R.id.edsub1);
         urdu = findViewById(R.id.edsub2);
         math = findViewById(R.id.edsub3);
         bio = findViewById(R.id.edsub4);
         phy = findViewById(R.id.edsub5);
         comp = findViewById(R.id.edsub6);
         chem = findViewById(R.id.edsub7);
         r = findViewById(R.id.edroll);
         ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, subject);  
         // Here I have pass Subject string to the adapter
 
         sp1.setAdapter(ad);
         sp2.setAdapter(ad);
         sp3.setAdapter(ad);
         sp4.setAdapter(ad);
         sp5.setAdapter(ad);
         sp6.setAdapter(ad);
         sp7.setAdapter(ad);
         sp1.setAdapter(ad);
 
         // this on click listen that give the position of the subject that user choose
 
         sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                 String item = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 Toast.makeText(Addresult.this, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
         });
     } 
     //this is my add result funtions
 
     public void addResult(View v) {
         String English = eng.getText().toString();
         String Urdu = urdu.getText().toString();
         String Math = math.getText().toString();
         String Bio = bio.getText().toString();
         String Physics = phy.getText().toString();
         String Computer = comp.getText().toString();
         String Chemistry = chem.getText().toString();
         String rol = r.getText().toString();
         if (English.equals("") || Urdu.equals("") || Math.equals("") || Bio.equals("") || Physics.equals("") || Computer.equals("") || Chemistry.equals("") || rol.equals("")) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all field first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else {
             int roll = Integer.parseInt(rol);
             resultmodel result = new resultmodel(English, Urdu, Math, Bio, hemistry, Physics, Computer, roll);
             int i = database.insertions(result);
             // I want to get value of spinner selected subject because I have store this subject by sequence into the SQLite database where I have created all subject by a sequence
           }
        }  
    }
}
```

This is my table where I keep a sequence of subjects :

```
private static String subject1 = "English";
private static String subject2 = "Urud";
private static String subject3 = "Math";
private static String subject4 = "Biology";
private static String subject5 = "Chemistry";
private static String subject6 = "Physics";
private static String subject7 = "Computer";
```

If I use each spinner for every select subject it is most time consuming approach can any other method is to achieve my goal:

[image]

Comment: in my previous some are mistake so I have update my question

Answer (score 1):

If the subject list is static and you want to get marks for all the subjects you dont need spinner, you can use recylerview to create dynamic list with each item containing subject `TextView` and `EditText` to enter marks.

Else if user can enter only selected subjects, you can keep a single `Spinner` and `EditText` at top with add `Button`, So that user can select a subject and enter marks and click add button. In add button click event, you should store the subject along with marks in a separate array. Then finally can insert all the entered values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of known subject fields, then there is no point in giving an option for selecting subjects, as you already need to enter marks of all subjects, here you can add `textView` for the subject's title and their corresponding `editText` for their marks.

If you have a use case, where users have to select some subjects out of a given list (not necessarily all of them), there you can use spinners for selecting subjects.

For selecting a spinner option, using the saved value from the database

```
spinner.setSelection(itemPosition);
```

`itemPosition` is an `int` and it is the position of the item in the adapter list. For your use case, you have to save the position of the item in the database, not the name.